# how do I invert the display order in item-view in DSpace?

Tags: java, xslt, dspace

I wanted to invert the page of the display order of "item-view" in dspace think this table page is harmful to the user. I wanted to make the downloadable files were shown above the table. Which parameters should I change?

Answer (score 1):

Your question did not specify which version of DSpace you are running.  I assume you are using XMLUI since you tagged the question with xslt.  Here is a solution referencing the Mirage theme in DSpace 5.x.  (If my assumptions are incorrect, please update your question.)

The following code is used to display an item.

These lines display the metadata.
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L50-L52

These lines display the file objects.
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L54-L83

A simple first step would be to change the order of these calls in the xslt template.

The following page outlines how to customize XMLUI: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/XMLUI+Configuration+and+Customization

Do you already have a custom theme?  If so, override this template in your custom theme.

If not, you will want to read about XMLUI overlays.  You will simply need to copy the files you wish to override into dspace/modules/xmlui/... and apply your changes there.